# Maven archetype: Generate directories

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I'm trying to get my maven archetype to generate directory structure based on user input from things like package and artifactId.

The idea, is that I have a class template:

```java
package ${package}.endpoints.${rootArtifactId};

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

/** Example resource class hosted at the URI path "/myresource"
*/
@Path("/echo")
public class Echo {

/** Method processing HTTP GET requests, producing "text/plain" MIME media
 * type.
 * @return String that will be send back as a response of type "text/plain".
 */
@GET 
@Produces("text/plain")
public String say() {
    return "Hi there!";
 }
}
```

And the package is being generated fine using the string replacement, but I would like to have the output folder for this file to also be /$package/endpoints/$artifactId

I could not find a way of doing that. I'm able to replace single files using __artifactId__-context.xml for instance. But I don't know how to force maven to create subfolders for the velocity template files.

Any ideas?

Comment: The following blog entry describes a dirty hack that might also work for your scenario:
http://marekdec.wordpress.com/2010/01/25/how-to-get-maven-archetype-to-generate-empty-directories/

Comment: So it is not possible to create subdirectories based on GroupId or package?

Comment: @cringe : it IS possible to create subdirectories based on groupId and/or package, but it is not very intuitive, and not quite flexible. See the article link added by DB5, that helped me.